# Support needed on dynamic SQL where trying to name the columns based on the current month where I get a syntax issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, syntax-error

I am working on the below script where I am trying to work on the stored procedure to generate the purchaseforcast in months but the query is grouping the months not in MONTH & YEAR.

Currently the query is grouping Mar all together irrespective of the year  but I would need the results by month & year

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[S4SP_MonthlyPfcstReport]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
    DECLARE @forecast1 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast2 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast3 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast4 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast5 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast6 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast7 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast8 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast9 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast10 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast11 varchar(50);
    DECLARE @forecast12 varchar(50);

    SET @forecast1 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(GETDATE()),YEAR(GETDATE()));
    SET @forecast2 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast3 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast4 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast5 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 4, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 4, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast6 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 5, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 5, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast7 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 6, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 6, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast8 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 7, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 7, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast9 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 8, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 8, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast10 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 9, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 9, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast11 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 10, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 10, GETDATE())));
    SET @forecast12 = dbo.GetMonthandYear_Func(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 11, GETDATE())),YEAR(DATEADD(month, 11, GETDATE())));

    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = ''; 

    SET @query = 'DROP VIEW IF EXISTS [dbo].[CWE_MonthlyPfcstReport_Deliverydate];';
  
    EXEC sp_executesql @query;

    SET @query = 'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CWE_MonthlyPfcstReport_Deliverydate] AS WITH OrderForecast AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT [articleCode] = pfCode
             , [orderRequirements] = toOrder + purchaseForecast
             , [orderSequence] = MONTH(orderDate)
             , [orderYear] = YEAR(orderDate)
        FROM PurchaseForecast
        WHERE orderDate <> ''''
    ) TabSource
    PIVOT (
        SUM([orderRequirements]) FOR [orderSequence] IN (MONTH(GETDATE()), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 4, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 5, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 6, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 7, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 8, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 9, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 10, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 11, GETDATE())))
    ) PivSource
)
SELECT [Code] = article.articleCode
     , [Article Description] = [description]
     , [Slim4 ABC Class] = abcClass
     , [Supplier] = primarySupplier
     , [Category] = uD1
     , [3] AS ''' + trim(@forecast1) + ''' 
     , [4] AS ''' + trim(@forecast2) + ''' 
     , [5] AS ''' + trim(@forecast3) + ''' 
     , [6] AS ''' + trim(@forecast4) + ''' 
     , [7] AS ''' + trim(@forecast5) + ''' 
     , [8] AS ''' + trim(@forecast6) + ''' 
     , [9] AS ''' + trim(@forecast7) + ''' 
     , [10] AS ''' + trim(@forecast8) + '''
     , [11] AS ''' + trim(@forecast9) + '''
     , [12] AS ''' + trim(@forecast10) + '''
     , [1] AS ''' + trim(@forecast11) + '''
     , [2] AS ''' + trim(@forecast12) + '''
FROM Article
LEFT JOIN OrderForecast ON Article.articleCode = OrderForecast.articleCode
WHERE nonStocked = 0
AND OrderForecast.orderYear = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
AND OrderForecast.orderSequence IN (MONTH(GETDATE()), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 4, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 5, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 6, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 7, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 8, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 9, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 10, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 11, GETDATE())))
';

--execute dynamic query
exec sp_executesql @query 

END
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CWE_MonthlyPfcstReport_Deliverydate, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 22]
> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Desired result: I would need the data to be grouped by Month & Year dynamically.

```
Code    Article Description Slim4 ABC Class Supplier    Category    Mar 23  Apr 23  May 23  Jun 23  Jul 23  Aug 23  Sep 23  Oct 23  Nov 23  Dec 23  Jan 24  Feb 24
UKGK001966  LOCK Kryptolok STD/Flex Twinpack    A   S00746      9000    9720    9720    9000    9720    8280    15480   19080   5400    6480    8640    12960
```

-- =============================================

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: It's microsoft SQL server

Comment: **Line 22** - which one is that?

Comment: Using Microsoft server management studio v18.9.2

Comment: The error message references line 22 (and 12 too), where the syntax error is found.

Comment: You can't PIVOT expressions like this: SUM([orderRequirements]) FOR [orderSequence] IN (MONTH(GETDATE()), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 4, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 5, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 6, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 7, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 8, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 9, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 10, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, 11, GETDATE())))

Comment: The best you could do is step back and rewrite the whole thing, it's too complicated. As Bogdan used to say, BUNO NO

Comment: Thanks...I have tried pivot as below as well but didn't work    [orderSequence] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])